# Use sed to insert another sed command in a file

Tags: linux, unix, sed

I am trying to use sed to insert sed command at the end of each line in a file using -

`sed -r 's/$/ | sed -r s\/abc\/xyz\/ /' filename.extension`

What I want next is to have single quotes around the inner sed. So that it will look something like-

`sed -r 's/$/ | sed -r 's\/abc\/xyz\/' /' filename.extension`

I tried escaping the inner single quotes, but no use.

Basically, I want the following lines -

`line 1
 line 2
 line 3`

to turn into-

`line 1 | sed -r 's/abc/xyz/'
 line 2 | sed -r 's/abc/xyz/'
 line 3 | sed -r 's/abc/xyz/'`

I am unable to get the single quotes, even with the escape characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed -e "s:$: | sed -r 's/abc/xyz/':" yourfile
```

Your problem is an example of the general case of nesting shell expressions. There are a number of ways to do this.

1. Use alternate delimiters. That's what I did here.
2. Assign subexpressions to variables, and then expand them.
3. Use lots of `\` escapes.
4. Put your subexpression in a file and `read` it.

Comment: I am not replacing abc with xyz. It has another regex inside the second sed command, hence the quotes.

Comment: Aha, well, I'm glad you condensed your example to something minimal, and you also specified an example of desired behavior. That's the right way to ask questions.

Answer (score 2):

Use alternative delimiter in inner sed and double quote in outer sed to simplify your command:

```
sed "s/$/ | sed -r 's~abc~xyz~'/" file.ext
```

btw `-r` is not really needed in inner sed

Comment: What is the difference between single quote and double quote with respect to bash?

Comment: You cannot nest single quote inside another single quote in shell

Comment: Yes, it did. The single quote now can be printed to the file. Although, I had escape numbers and backslashes (in the replacement string of the inner sed) as - 

`sed "s/$/ | sed -r 's~([0-9]+).*~\\\1~'/" filename.ext`

Trying to figure out why only the replacement string needs escaping and not the string after the 1st delimiter of the inner sed i.e. "([0-9]+)" this

Comment: When using double quotes every escape needs to be doubled up so `\1` will become `\\1`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/$/ | sed -r '\''s\/abc\/xyz\/'\''/' file
```

Use `'\''` to end the current single quote, then in the shell use `\'` to quote a single quote and finally a single quote to start the quoting of the sed command. Use `\/` to quote the forward slash in the sed command.

As the substitution command can use any delimiter:

```
sed 's#$# | sed -r '\''s/abc/xyz/'\''#' file
```

reduces the amount of quoting and:

```
sed "s#$# | sed -r 's/abc/xyz/'#" file
```

reduces it further. However double quoting sed commands (or any utility) can have unwanted side effects i.e. metacharacters can be evaluated by the shell, so it is best to single quote and live with the "hole-like" mechanism `'\''`.